# How to select wifi channel with windows 7 adhoc?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I made an adhoc network with Windows 7. Now I would like to change the wifi channel it is using. How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to change the channel is a function of the wifi adapter driver.  Some can, some can't.

If yours can, you'll find it in the wifi adapter properties.

> 1. Press the Windows logo and "R" keys simultaneously to display the "Run" dialog box. Type "devmgmt.msc" without quotation marks into the
>      box and press "Enter." The Windows device manager will appear.
> 2. Double-click "Network Adapters" to expand the category.
> 3. Right-click your wireless network adapter and click "Properties."
> 4. Click the "Advanced" tab, then click "Ad Hoc Channel 802.11" under "Property" on the left side of the window.
> 5. Use the arrows on the right side of the window to change the channel. Make sure that you and your ad hoc networking partner select
>      the same channel.
> 6. Click "OK" to save the change, then close the device manager.

<sub>[source](http://www.ehow.com/how_6188303_change-channel-wifi-connection-router.html)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. This confirms the issue. Clearly Atheros AR9285 drivers can't change it.

Answer (score 4):

When installing the Windows drivers for the Atheros device, the INF file may not have included Ad Hoc channel selection capability even though the wifi card is capable.

Look for 'defaultIbssChannel' examples in the INF file.
You can then add this new parameter by using 'regedit' and add to the existing parameters that are available to the wifi card.
Look in:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/ControlSet 001/Class/.....NDI/params

Eventually, you may want to modify the INF file and re-install the driver.

I had the same problem with the AR9280 chipset and was able to set the Ad Hoc channel by tinkering as above.

Comment: Hi glenn; I did follow your instructions and found the inf file and created the defaultIbssChannel values in the registry in 'CurrentControlSet', 'ControlSet 001', 'ControlSet 002'; the option to change the channel is added now to the advanced properties of the driver but changing the channel doesn't take effect; Any thought?

Comment: reset the wifi card (disable/enable the interface).  the change should take effect immediately.  Also, be aware that there is a thing called IBSS merge.  If you are connecting to an existing ad hoc network, your wifi card will change its channel to the established network's channel.  However, if you're the first one up, your wifi card should pick the default channel you selected.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out how to change the channel used by the Microsoft Virtual Miniport Adapter, which is used by 3rd party routers and Ad-hoc connections.

A full description can be downloaded here:
http://www.necon.co.za/xx/WiFi_Router.pdf

> - Connect to a sample Wi-Fi network running on the s
>     ame channel as that required (e.g. channel 6)
> - Run the router software so that it adopts the same
>     channel (e.g. channel 6)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.