# Change the channel of a Windows 7 wifi hosted network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, netsh

I'm having performance problems with my phone connecting to a Windows 7 wifi hosted network. My phone can connect to the network and somewhat browse the web but the connection is sluggish - the latency seems very high even when I'm actively browsing the web on the phone.

I read somewhere (sorry, can't find the link) that this could be due to channel interference and so I've been trying without success to change the channel of my hosted network. I tried following [another guide from this site](https://superuser.com/questions/520060/how-to-select-wifi-channel-with-windows-7-adhoc) but that seems to be related to ad-hoc connections only (which doesn't work with Android devices anyway).

Any ideas on how to change the channel in my case? Or in suggestions on something I could do to improve the connectivity?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about changing the channel of your wireless, but if you'd like to confirm your theory, I'd check out inSSIDer. I've had success with it in the past.

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention that I did use WifiAnalyzer and saw that my current channel is indeed being interfered with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosted network uses the channel set on your wireless card.

**Setting channel directly**

If you want to set the channel directly or use a free channel, then this method won't work for you. If you are lucky, you can set the channel in the ["wifi adapter properties"](https://superuser.com/a/520069/244361).

You can also search for third party tools to configure your wireless card. Some years ago I used Intel ProSet for this task.

**Setting channel indirectly**

First you should find which channels are used in your area. I used [Meraki WiFi Stumbler](https://tools.meraki.com/stumbler#q=) to do this. I had my channel set to 11, which was shared by ~15 networks nearby. This caused my phone to lose wifi connection about once per minute.

Find a channel that is used by 1-2 networks. Choose one of these networks and simply connect to it. Enter any arbitrary text when asked for a password. The important part is that your system tries to connect to the network.

The channel of your wireless card should now be the same as the targeted network. You can check the channel by typing: `netsh wlan show hostednetwork`

**Note:** I have not tested what happens if you successfully connect to the network.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately setting the WiFi card channel for a hosted network is very hardware dependent and not many external USB Wifi dongles support it on Windows, even though many have been made to work on Linux. There have also been some limited success in editing the driver INF file. Especially troublesome wifi HW are those based on the Intel or Qualcomm Atheros chipsets.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066440/change-the-channel-of-a-wireless-windows-8-hosted-network/32200684#32200684) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/520060/how-to-select-wifi-channel-with-windows-7-adhoc/520069#520069) are some ideas on how to hack the driver files.