# Is it possible to specify the channel I want to use when connecting to an SSID that is being broadcast on multiple channels (Windows 8)?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am at a school and am connecting to an SSID being broadcast from 3 different access points on 3 different channels (eg. 1, 6, 11). Sometimes, when I connect to the SSID, it is through one of the access points with lower signal strength. Is there a method, through command prompt or some other way, to connect to a particular access point when connecting to an SSID?  Here's a link to a picture of the problem:

[image]

I want to connect to BSSID 2, not BSSID 1 or 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select wifi channel with windows 7 adhoc?](http://superuser.com/questions/520060/how-to-select-wifi-channel-with-windows-7-adhoc)

Comment: I don't think this question is even close to the linked ad hoc network question.

Comment: Do you really mean 3 different routers?  I suspect you mean 3 access points connected to the same network.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I don't think [How to select wifi channel with windows 7 adhoc](http://superuser.com/questions/520060/how-to-select-wifi-channel-with-windows-7-adhoc) applies to my question. I am not trying to switch the channel that my adhoc network is broadcasting on. I am trying to switch which channel my wifi adapter is connecting to (on a network hosted by someone else with multiple access points).

Comment: What NIC are you using? If your driver provides for locking to a channel then you'll be able to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply Linef4ult. I am using an Intel Dual Band wireless-n 7260 adapter. Is that what you meant by NIC? Would you happen to have a link to instructions on how to lock to a channel, or do you know how I would go about doing so?